# How to output True if these methods equal each other?

Tags: python-3.x

I will be given a type of farm animals and the age of the animals.  If I get two animals with the same age, how do I return True.

I understand how to make it return true if I am giving the two items in the function, but I am not sure how to do it in the main function.

```
from src.winged_animal import WingedAnimal
class Chicken(WingedAnimal):

    def __init__(self, age):
        WingedAnimal.__init__(self, age)

    def chicken_equal(self, age):
        if self.age == self.age
            return True


    def make_sound(self):
        return WingedAnimal.make_sound(self) + " - cluck, cluck"
```

Given Chicken(1.1) and Chicken(1.1) I want to return that they equal each other in the method chicken_equal.  I don't even know how to begin this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__

Comment: Thank you so much I figured it out from that I appreciate it

Comment: If you have the time, I recommend reading that whole page, it's one of the coolest pieces of Python documentation. I learn something every time I read it.

Comment: I will do that so far it is helping classes make a lot more sense thank you for the help.

Comment: the link Boris suggested is for method comparison. You are obviously confused and mixing methods analysis with and actual comparison of variables against each other. You should first value x (animal type (x1 = chicken and x2 = chicken) and then y (age of x1 = 1 and x2 = age 1). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
x1 = ["chicken", 1]
x2 = ["chicken", 1]
x = [x1, x2]

result = [0, 0]  # [animal type , age]

for item in x:
    if item[0] == "chicken":   # animal type
        result[0] = result[0] + 1
    if item[1] == 1:   # age
        result[1] = result[1] + 1

print (result)   # if 2, 2 then both are equal; in all other cases not.
```